# convert generics to int or char java

Tags: java, generics, casting

I have a class depending on Generics. In real, this can be `int` or `char`. Respectively, I want to run either a method `methodInt(int[] intArray)` or `methodChar(char[] charArray)`.

```
private void method(Class<Gen> genClass, Gen[] genArray) throws Exception {
        if(int.class.isAssignableFrom(genClass)) {
            // Here I want to run methodInt(genArray));
        }
        else if(char.class.isAssignableFrom(genClass)) {
            // Here I want to run methodChar(genArray);
        }
        else {
            // throw an execption
        }
    }
```

Of course, the types are not convertible but is there a way to do that ?

Edit : would it be a bad practice to set `intArray`, `charArray` field set them in the overloaded constructors, and then putting :

```
private void method(Class<Gen> genClass) throws Exception {
            if(int.class.isAssignableFrom(genClass)) {
                methodInt(intArray));
            }
            else if(char.class.isAssignableFrom(genClass)) {
                methodChar(charArray);
            }
            else {
                // throw an execption
            }
        }
```

Comment: If this is just about two typs, `int` and `char`, then it looks like you should rather go with method overloading in the beginning instead of using generics here.

Comment: It definitely *can't* be `int` or `char`, since you can't use generics for primitive types.

Comment: Have you considered a method overloading?

Comment: If `Gen` represents, say, `Integer` you can use [`ArrayUtils.toPrimitive`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#toPrimitive%28java.lang.Integer[]%29) to convert `genArray` to an `int[]`.

Comment: @KevinEsche I edited my post. Do you consider this as a bad practice ?

Comment: @primatur it´s quite uneccessary if you can just call `methodInt` and `methodChar` directly. And if your class does use generics but should be used for only two specific Object types then it quitly defeats the purpose of using generics. Imagine someone is trying to call this method with another class then these two and is constantly running into your exception. The last thing that would come into his mind would be that this class can only be used with an `Integer` or a `Char`